# channel_not_found error while sending a message to myself

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I'm using python3.6 and trying to send message to myself to start interacting in slack.

I've installed `pip install slackclient` and am using slackclient v2.2.1

channel ID is extracted from slack link of my account `https://XXXXX.slack.com/messages/XXXXXXXXX`

I would like to see Hi message in my slack account. any suggestions.

````
client = slack.WebClient("BOT_USER_TOKEN", timeout=30)
client.chat_postMessage(
    channel='CHANNEL_ID',
    text='Hi!')```
````

Comment: What response do you get from Slack?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken This is what I get ```The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'channel_not_found'}``` I also found out that private channels in which I am not part of will not be visible to me, but I want to start from basic. sending a Hi message to myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bot user token is linked to a bot user that is created with your app. If you use the bot token you will only have access to channels that this bot user is a member of.

So to make your script work you need to do one of the following:

- Use the access token instead of the bot token (that one is linked to the user that installed the Slack app)
- Invite the bot user to the channel you are trying to send a message to

As you want to start with basics, I would recommend to use public channels first, which will always work.

Direct messages are a little bit more complicated. To send a direct message to a user (e.g. from your bot user to yourself) you need to first open a direct message channel with [`conversations.open`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open), which will give you a new channel ID. And then use that channel ID for sending a message.

Comment: I shall try this and update you, Thanks @Erik Kalkoken

Comment: @epsan If this answer solved your issue please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the checkmark. thanks!

Comment: I have considered other options for simplicity, haven't tried your method since this seems to be complex. Thanks. yet marked it as an answer for others who might need similar help.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken In oauth2.0 I am unable to ask for scope which is "chat:write:bot".
I was able to solve channel_not_found issue with your solution of access_token but now I am not able to request that scope.
Is there any other possible workaround?